# What is the best way to add an index column to SQL Server view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given a SQL Server table (Table1) and view (View1) defined as `SELECT * FROM Table1`

What is the **best** way to add a column containing an index value (e.g. 1,2,3,...n) for each row?

The result would be something like...

- 1, Product1, Price1
- 2, Product2, Price2
- 3, Product3, Price3

Where the first column in the bullet list above is calculated/computed in the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the simplest is `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as index_value,
       . . .
. . .
```

If you have a particular ordering in mind, you can use that logic instead of `(select null)`.

Comment: That works a treat.  I've 2 OVER clauses in my actual query.  I didn't think it was possible to have more than 1.  I stand corrected.

Comment: Even shorter `row_number() over (order by 1/0) `

Comment: @LukaszSzozda it's not documented that that expression will never be evaluated.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I hope one day it would, similar case `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1/0)`